# Validate url in JS using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a regex to validate a URL with conditions below:

Ex:

> www.google.com
>
> www.google.com/[any_params]
>
> http://google.com/[any_params]
>
> https://google.com/[any_params]
>
> google.com/[any_params]

I used this regex:

```
/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/
```

but it's returning false with this case: www.google.com

or returning true with this case: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2JZC.png]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `www.google.com/` is a path relative URL since it has no protocol.

Comment: `ftp://`, `http://`, or `https://` is required at the beginning, with the regex you have. If you want to make that optional, wrap it in `()` and put a `?` after it

Comment: Hi Mike, i was add new required above.
Hi Lan, can you help me with required above?

Comment: Hmm, i will try now. Thanks talles, i will feedback.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help.
In my case, it's valid. 
Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

The following regular expression should work for you:

```
var regex = /^(ftp:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-\/]))?$/;
```